# Using promises and async with socket.io doesn't return expected results

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, socket.io, async-await

I'm very new to promises. I need my server to wait for socket connections from an external api and from browser clients connections. The external api sends a number of objects (4 in this example) to the server, which is received as a promise and calls the function which waits for the promise. For each object received by the promise, a browser client can make a connection (promise) and join the game.

I have a function which should wait for variables to be populated by these two promises. It is successful in waiting for the external api objects, but it never receives the promise to indicate that the correct number of clients have made connections.

I wrapped the socket listening for the external API objects in a promise as it will only we sent once. I also call the function which handles the two promises here as it didn't seem to work anywhere else.

```
//HANDLER FOR GAME OBJECT SENT FROM MAX API
const maxPromise = new Promise ((resolve) => {
    socket.on("dictData", async (data)=>{
        try {
            let {songName, level, imageArr} = data;
            let [imageObj] = imageArr;
            gameVars.songName = songName;
            gameVars.level = level;
            let gameObject = {};
            for (let obj in imageArr) {
            let objectId = imageArr[obj].name;
            gameObject.objectId = objectId;
            gameObject.path = imageObj.path;
            // gameObject.files = imageObj.imagePath;
            gameState.totalServerCount ++;
            gameState.serverList.push({gameObject});
            }
            resolve(gameState.serverList) //resolve the promise with the array of objects
            sendData()
        } 
        catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    });
});
```

I also wrapped the client req listener in a promise because after countless tries to nest the promise inside, this was the only solution which didn't return the actual socket as the promise, so I feel this is probably the closest solution for me.

This promise should only resolve when there are the same amount of client connections as there are server objects received in the first promise. I a testing by simply connecting from 4 open tabs to localhost:3000.

```
//HANDLER FOR CLIENT REQUEST TO JOIN GAME
const playerPromise = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    socket.on('joinGame', async () => {
        try {
            gameState.totalPlayerCount++;
            gameState.playerList.push(socket.id)
                switch (true) {
                    case gameState.totalPlayerCount < gameState.totalServerCount : 
                        console.log("Not enough players", gameState.totalPlayerCount)
                        break; 
                    case gameState.totalPlayerCount <= gameState.totalServerCount :
                        console.log("Counts are equal", gameState)
                        readyPlayers = true; 
                        resolve(gameState.playerList)
                        break; 
                    case gameState.totalServerCount == 0 :
                        console.log("Server not ready", gameState)
                        break; 
                    default : 
                        console.log("Too many players", gameState.totalPlayerCount)
                        reject("Too many players", gameState.playerList)
                }
        }
        catch(e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    })
})
```

sendData() function logs the 1st and 2nd tests to the console, but never the 3rd.

```
    async function sendData() {
        try {
            console.log("TEST1")
            const dataMax = await maxPromise;
            console.log("TEST2", dataMax)
            const dataPlay = await playerPromise;
            console.log("TEST3", dataPlay)
            for (var key in await dataPlay) {
                io.to(dataPlay[key]).emit('gameData', dataPlay[key]);
            }
        }
        catch(e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    };
```

I've looked at every other similar post on stackoverflow and online but cannot find any solution to this or where I'm going wrong. I have also devised the above solution with minimal knowledge of socket.io and promises, so is there is a better/cleaner way to do the above please let me know.

EDIT:
This is my current solution using only one promise, but now the promise is not being populated at all in the send function:

```
//HANDLER FOR GAME OBJECT SENT FROM MAX API
const maxPromise = new Promise ((resolve) => {
    socket.on("dictData", async (data)=>{
        try {
            let {songName, level, imageArr} = data;
            let [imageObj] = imageArr;
            gameVars.songName = songName;
            gameVars.level = level;
            let gameObject = {};
            for (let obj in imageArr) {
            let objectId = imageArr[obj].name;
            gameObject.objectId = objectId;
            gameObject.path = imageObj.path;
            gameState.totalServerCount ++;
            gameState.serverList.push({gameObject});
            }
            resolve(gameState.serverList) 
        } 
        catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    });
});
```

```
    async function sendData(playerData) {
        try {
            console.log("TEST1")
            const dataMax = await maxPromise;
            console.log("TEST2")
            for (var key in await playerData) {
                io.to(playerData[key]).emit('gameData', dataMax);
            }
        }
        catch(e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    };
```

The sendData() is called in the Client socket handler which just passes the array of connections as playerData. "TEST2" is never logged.

Seeing as the promise maxPromise is global, shouldn't it be able to access its value?

Comment: For starters, please go read about what `await` is useful for.  You appear to be just throwing it in lots of places where it does nothing useful.  `await` ONLY does anything useful when you `await` a promise.  `await data`, `await imageArr` and `await resolve()` aren't doing anything useful, etc...

Comment: I just started putting those there out of frustration when it was not originally working, I'll remove them

Comment: Please learn how it works rather than just guessing at stuff.  It will help you a lot.

Comment: I really have tried, I may be too ADHD for this stuff

Comment: Architecturally, it's unusual and often wrong to wrap an event handler with a promise because the event handler can fire many times, but the promise will only ever resolve or reject once.  Why are you doing it this way?  When  a certain condition occurs inside your event handler, why don't you just call the desired function?  Why use a promise here at all?

Comment: When I wrap the playerPromise in the joinGame socket function, it returned the entire socket as the promise resolve rather than the array of player id's I'm trying to get. I'm doing this as I first need to see how many game objects are sent from the Max API (they range from 3-6), then allow that many clients to connect, and send them a game object each.

Comment: It sounds to me like you just need to keep some state somewhere and in each of these event handlers, check the state to decide what functions to call.  I don't think event handlers that can occur more than once should be wrapped in a promise like this.

Comment: I've added my other solution to playerPromise which adds the socket func to a variable, but the promise just resolves as the socket itself

Comment: Your other solution is returning a promise into an event handler.  That means the promise just goes into oblivion and you can never use it.  I do not think promises are the right solution here.  You need to manage some state and check that state in your event handlers.

Comment: @jfriend00 is right you should not have a "socket.on.." inside a Promise! Promise will be only fulfilled once! This is a big mistake.

Comment: Thanks, I have created a new solution which I have updated on here but now the send function never receives the fulfilled promise because it isn't called within the promise function anymore. I know it's not correct to use promise even if the socket will only fire once but would really like to get some working solution before I give up for the day. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured this out by now. It's an interesting problem. I'd like to know how you solved it. As I understand it, you need to wait for data to arrive in order to select players. Seems like a good use of promises. You could use socket.once instead of socket.on for dictData if it's a one-time event

At the same time you don't want to block players yet still need to wait for enough players to join. Awaiting another promise is again a good gating technique

If you haven't solved all issues I suggest first removing socket.io from the equation while developing the gating logic. You can do this in node with custom event emitters. I'd simulate players and data events occurring at random times. You can also do this in the browser with custom events or broadcast channels. You'll find this more convenient than manually connecting to a port

I'd put in a lot of logging with millisecond timestamps to easily understand the sequence of events - when they occur and when they're handled